# Developing on an iPod iTouch - UIView Issues

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, ipod-touch

So I've been using this site for a lot of my questions. I'm very good with Googling problems and debugging even the worst error code, but this is something rather basic that I'm not able to figure out.

My UIView compared to what I actually see on the iTouch has always been a bit different. I'm not sure if this is xCode's IB just having larger graphics for its buttons, but in general there is this 20px height difference, to the point where if I set a button at the bottom of the UIView, it gets cut off. (I thought it was supposed to be 320x460..)

Normally I shrug this off because it hasn't been an issue till I've started to put scrolling into place with the login screen. xCode claims my view is 320x548, my app says its 320x480. If I resize my scroll size to 320x480, the view shrinks on the iTouch, leaving a large gap.

I have been using UIViews in the IB rather then a ViewController because I'm subviewing mixed with some nav control.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

http://oi49.tinypic.com/rrnjit.jpg  (when first loading)

http://oi50.tinypic.com/j8matu.jpg (scrolling down about 20 px..)

Comment: Is that an older iPod with the smaller screen size (I can't tell from the photos sorry)? If so, and if you're using Storyboards, you might want to check how the UI changes when you change the screen size - when viewing the Storyboard, click on Editor -> Apply Retina 3.5 Form Factor.

Comment: I've tried editing the form factor to 3.5, it cuts the view off pretty bad. I want to say this is a 4rth gen with the latest iOS 6.1.3

Comment: If the view looks bad when it's 3.5", you need to alter the autolayout constraints (or springs and struts if you're not using autolayout) to move the UI components around on resize.

Comment: The view doesnt look bad, its cut off as if I've set the view to be 320x460 and has this extra 128px of nothing at the bottom http://oi48.tinypic.com/2v85pxt.jpg

Comment: I meant 88px, which fits perfectly with the description of issues involving iphone5 having a larger screen then the iTouch UGH

Comment: Going to try and run this in the Simulator, of course xCode only lets me debug in the latest version of iOS and only lists iPhone 6.1 and I have to download the option to debug in 5.0 and 6.0

Comment: Yeah, if you want the layout to change based on the screen size you need to set up either autolayout constraints, or the springs and struts correctly. The alternative is to go with the fixed layout. If you're running in the simulator you can change the hardware to show you what it looks like on the 3.5" and 4" screens.

Comment: Thank you for your time! I think this issue may be *solved*. I think I just needed the correct wording + information. I found a few Q+As on here that talk resolution differences + how to deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make correct use of springs and struts or Auto Layout. You are probably designing your app for the 4 inch screen - in your Storyboard, there is an option to see how it would look on a 3:5 inch screen. Press that.

For more info, Google Auto Layout.